# Page Title Dependant On Input?

Tags: title

We recently implemented a stock quote system, where a user can enter a stock symbol and it will return all sorts of financial values.

I have a template made up that displays the financial widgets, and when a user enters a ticker symbol it runs some JS with the callback url being my template. In this example, it is something like this.

https://www.stocktrades.ca/quote/?qm_symbol=AAPL

What my issue is, is the title is currently blank. When a user inputs a symbol, the page title in the browser is simply “Quote -” Instead, I want it to be “Quote – XXXX” with XXXX being the stock ticker they entered.

What is the easiest way to go about this? I know it’s probably really simple, but I am stumped

Comment: Easiest way would be to use the JS to update the title (probably a `<h1>`) with the same callback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! One issue I have, and I was thinking of doing it that way, is typically shouldn't the page title be generated before the page generates? Putting it in that JS may delay that.

Comment: You should have a default - maybe "Your quote is loading" or something like that - then when you run the JS it can replace the title right as it displays the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to use existing WordPress filters to modify your page title. For your needs, the [the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_title/) filter would probably be your best best.

Here's a link to a pretty good [tutorial](https://wpshout.com/quick-guides/changing-wordpress-post-titles-appear-first-filter-hook-tutorial/) on using it.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code I ended up going with. Please let me know if there is anything wrong with this!

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'ps_wp_title_quote' );
    function ps_wp_title_quote( $title )
    {
    if(isset($_GET['qm_symbol'])){
        $qm_symbol = $_GET['qm_symbol'];
    }
    if (is_page('quote') ) {
           $title = __( 'Stock Information For', 'textdomain' ) .' '. $qm_symbol;
    }
    return $title;
    }
```

the problem I am still having though is when I place this in the functions.php file, when I enter a quote symbol it changes my navigation menu items to the title from this filter as well. When I add it directly into Quote.php, it works fine.

Another problem I am having, is it still doesn't reflect the title in the browser tab. It still just says "Quote - ". Any way to fix this?